# Starting CMMotionActivityManager gives SIGABRT

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, core-motion

I am trying to detect motion activities in a native Xamarin.iOS app, running on an iPhone 6s. I am starting the manager like this:

```
var _manager = new CMMotionActivityManager();
_manager.StartActivityUpdates(new NSOperationQueue(), (activity) =>
{
    // do something with activity 
});
```

When I run the app, it is failing with this error:

> 2017-07-01 11:38:51.722 iosapp[1095:318780] critical:  Native
>   stacktrace:
>
> 2017-07-01 11:38:51.813 iosapp[1095:318780] critical:     0
>   libmonosgen-2.0.dylib               0x00000001007d5920
>   mono_handle_native_crash + 260 2017-07-01 11:38:51.813
>   iosapp[1095:318780] critical:     1   libsystem_platform.dylib
>   0x000000018ca1131c _sigtramp + 52 2017-07-01 11:38:51.813
>   iosapp[1095:318780] critical:     2   libsystem_kernel.dylib
>   0x000000018c9484d0  + 100 2017-07-01 11:38:51.813
>   iosapp[1095:318780] critical:     3   libsystem_kernel.dylib
>   0x000000018c9484fc system_set_sfi_window + 0 2017-07-01 11:38:51.813
>   iosapp[1095:318780] critical:     4   TCC
>   0x000000018fb64498  + 0 2017-07-01 11:38:51.813
>   iosapp[1095:318780] critical:     5   TCC
>   0x000000018fb643b8  + 0 2017-07-01 11:38:51.813
>   iosapp[1095:318780] critical:     6   TCC
>   0x000000018fb673d4  + 340 2017-07-01 11:38:51.813
>   iosapp[1095:318780] critical:     7   libxpc.dylib
>   0x000000018ca46f38  + 80 2017-07-01 11:38:51.814
>   iosapp[1095:318780] critical:     8   libxpc.dylib
>   0x000000018ca46ea8  + 40 2017-07-01 11:38:51.814
>   iosapp[1095:318780] critical:     9   libdispatch.dylib
>   0x000000018c80a9a0  + 16 2017-07-01 11:38:51.814
>   iosapp[1095:318780] critical:     10  libdispatch.dylib
>   0x000000018c8190d4  + 644 2017-07-01 11:38:51.814
>   iosapp[1095:318780] critical:     11  libdispatch.dylib
>   0x000000018c81aa50  + 540 2017-07-01 11:38:51.814
>   iosapp[1095:318780] critical:     12  libdispatch.dylib
>   0x000000018c81a7d0  + 124 2017-07-01 11:38:51.814
>   iosapp[1095:318780] critical:     13  libsystem_pthread.dylib
>   0x000000018ca13100 _pthread_wqthread + 1096 2017-07-01 11:38:51.814
>   iosapp[1095:318780] critical:     14  libsystem_pthread.dylib
>   0x000000018ca12cac start_wqthread + 4 2017-07-01 11:38:51.814
>   iosapp[1095:318780] critical: 
>   ================================================================= Got a SIGABRT while executing native code. This usually indicates a fatal
>   error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries  used by your
>
> ## application.

Is there something wrong with the way that I am instantiating the manager?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. It was a permission issue with info.plist.

From [iOS Core Motion docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coremotion):

> Important An iOS app linked on or after iOS 10.0 must include usage
>   description keys in its Info.plist file for the types of data it
>   needs. Failure to include these keys will cause the app to crash. To
>   access motion and fitness data specifically, it must include
>   NSMotionUsageDescription.

After I included this key in the info.plist:

```
<key>NSMotionUsageDescription</key>
<string>MotionActivity App needs Motion Access</string>
```

it works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Might need a bit more code but, try using the main NSOperationQueue

```
public void StartMotionUpdates (Action<ActivityType> handler)
        {
            motionActivityMgr.StartActivityUpdates (NSOperationQueue.MainQueue, ((activity) => {
                handler (ActivityDataManager.ActivityToType (activity));
            }));
        }
```

Note* I initialized in the constructor
`motionActivityMgr = new CMMotionActivityManager ();`
I'm going off of the sample:
https://github.com/xamarin/ios-samples/blob/master/ios8/MotionActivityDemo/MotionActivityDemo/ActivityDataManager.cs

Comment: Figured it out. See my answer. Thanks